# "Cannot Resolve IProjectServices" with Interfaces for Service Layer in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.  I have a project called Project.Services that contains a bunch of services that the controllers in my MVC application leverage.

In terms of exposing the Services project to the Web Project - I have an interface defined in my web project called "IProjectServices" with a bunch of blank methods that correspond to what I need.

I then attempt to implement this interface in the Services Project by using syntax like

```
public class ProjectServices : IProjectServices
```

I'm getting a "cannot resolve IProjectServices" error now - before I start digging into this, am I using interfaces correctly here?

I'm thinking the web project is saying "hey I need some kind of services but I don't want to depend directly on the services project so I'll create an interface" and then the Services project is saying "hey no problem I'll implement that, but maybe another project (like tests) will implement it differently in the future so we're not tightly coupled".  Am I thinking right?

Comment: Move your interface over to your Project.Services project, you can still handle the DI with an external project/dll dependency.

Comment: So in my Services project I will have IProjectServices and ProjectServices?  How will the Web project know about the interface?

Comment: If both projects are in the same solution... Right click the references folder, and add a project reference

Comment: Oh... and then DI "injects" the Interface into the Web Project?

Comment: No.. compiler will do that.  You could use an IOC container and configure it to inject a ProjectServices implementation into your code that has this IProjectServices dependency.

Comment: I'm so confused... "could use" or "would use"?  The implementation is currently in the Services project - the IOC container would push the *implementation* into the dependent code, not the *interface*?

Comment: you might start out by just instantiating a "new  ProjectServices();"   before you pull in dependency injection... check out this, looks promising for learning the ropes: [msdn 30 min mvc DI training](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection.aspx)

Comment: I tried that tutorial but the format is really frustrating, tough for me to follow.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example implementation using Unity.  I hope this helps.

Working backward from the controller...

MVC Project: DashboardController.cs

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDashboardService dashboardService;

    public DashboardController(IDashboardService dashboardService)
    {
        this.dashboardService = dashboardService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = this.dashboardService.BuildIndexViewModel();

        return this.View(model);
    }
}
```

MVC Project: Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Standard MVC setup
        // ...

        // Application configuration 
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        new AppName.Services.UnityBootstrap().Configure(container);
    }
}
```

Services Project: DashboardService.cs

```
public class DashboardService : IDashboardService
{
    // ctor
    // ...

    public IndexViewModel BuildIndexViewModel()
    {
        var currentPerformanceYear = this.repository.GetMaxPerformanceYear().PerformanceYearID;
        var staff = this.repository.GetStaffBySamAccountName(this.currentUser.Identity.Name);

        var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            StaffName = staff.FullName,
            StaffImageUrl = staff.StaffImageUrl,
            // ...
        };

        return model;
    }
}
```

Services Project: IDashboardService.cs

```
public interface IDashboardService
{
    IndexViewModel BuildIndexViewModel();
}
```

Services Project: UnityBootstrap.cs

```
public class UnityBootstrap : IUnityBootstrap
{
    public IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return container.RegisterType<IDashboardService, DashboardService>()
                        .RegisterType<ISharePointService, SharePointService>()
                        .RegisterType<IStaffService, StaffService>();
    }
}
```

Company Enterprise Library Utilities Project: IUnityBootstrap.cs

```
public interface IUnityBootstrap
{
    IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container);
}
```